# I am trying to add OAUTH and I receive: An error saving your app has occurred

Tags: api, oauth

I am trying to add OAUTH and I receive:  An error saving your app has occurred

I am using the super admin and same for Developer email.

Any help is appreciated... thanks

I am trying to add IDRIVE for Google Workspace access for backup.
I created the project and added the API's and now the OAUTH is err...

An error saving your app has occurred

Answer (score 0):

Did you try filling in all required fields? The ones with red stars by them. If so, you probably need to use the "add domain" option, which has a required field under it as well. You can fill that area out and then try submitting.